# Change starting point for UINavigationController to detail UIViewController without loosing its context?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How can I change the starting point for a `UINavigationController` using a `Storyboard` without loosing its context?

I have a simple `Storyboard` with a `UINavigationController` including a `UICollectionView` as overview and a `UIViewController` as detail viewcontroller.

[image: Screenshot]

As long as I have the starting arrow pointing to the `UINavigationController`, it works fine. However I want to launch directly with latest detail `UIViewController` (on the right) opened skipping the `UICollectionView`. But when I drag the starting arrow to the detail controller I run into issues:

- the actual detail ViewController content that is being populated in the `prepareForSegue` method in the `UICollectionView`is then missing
- the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` in the detail view controller is not working as well. So it's not possible to go back to the overview `UICollecionView`

What's the best way to change the start up `UIViewController` without loosing its navigationControl context and `preparefForSegue` population method?

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.mavigationController setViewControllers:@[…] animated:YES];
```

// just set any `UIViewController`s array you want, you can replace or filter it. The last one in your array will be shown on the screen.